# Order of sections produced by NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios8, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Does a `NSFetchedResultsController` assign values for the attribute identified by `sectionNameKeyPath` to sections always in ascending order?

For instance if my `sectionNameKeyPath` were an (optional) boolean attribute with values `@(YES)`, `@(NO)`, `@(YES)`, would the first section receive one row (because `NO` corresponds to `0`) and the second section receive two (because `YES` corresponds to `1`)?

So is that the case and if that is, can one change the order (without introducing another attribute that "inverses" the first)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortDescriptors` is what actually sorts the objects. `sectionNameKeyPath` simply describes where the section borders should be given that sorting (one section per unique value).

Comment: True. I had forgotten to set a primary sort descriptor on `sectionNameKeyPath` (for ordering the sections) next to the (now secondary) sort descriptor (for ordering objects inside sections) in `NSFetchedResultsController`s fetch request.